# How to override PropertyDescriptor.GetValue and PropertyDescriptor.SetValue for dynamic object in .NET 4

Tags: c#, dynamic, binding, c#-4.0

We are using `DynamicObject` for dynamic properties creation, but then we want to use `PropertyGrid` to show this properties and edit them.

Firstly, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx) article, and this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37026/Csharp-4-0-Dynamic-s-compiler-tricks.aspx). I try to use second article code, but in more generic fashion, basically to replace all methods names constants with variables. But the problem is that VS2010 can't find `CSharpGetMemberBinder` type.

Does someone know how to replace it? or what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using that article's Helper class (which is outdated), you can simply cast to IDictionary and set / retrieve the values:

```
        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            if (_owner != component) throw new InvalidOperationException("GetValue can only be used with the descriptor's owner.");
            //return DynamicHelper.GetValue(component, _propertyName);
            return ((IDictionary<String, object>)component)[_propertyName];
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            if (_owner != component) throw new InvalidOperationException("SetValue can only be used with the descriptor's owner.");
            OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
            //DynamicHelper.SetValue(component, _propertyName, value);
            ((IDictionary<String, object>)component)[_propertyName] = value;
        }
```

Edit: This may only work in the case of ExpandoObjects, which was what the article was using.. if you created your own dynamic class with a different backing, you may need to change this.

Comment: Yes, it's custom dynamic class derived from DynamicObject

Comment: Aldo if you want to be able to edit those check the public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(object); } } code. Quickly replacing it with string works for strings. If its object the PropertyGrid seems to be readonly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) it lets you invoke dynamic properties of ***any*** `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` by string name.

```
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return Dyanmic.InvokeGet(component,propertyName);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
         Dyanmic.InvokeSet(component,propertyName, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
CallSiteContainer.getLengthSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
    "Length",
    typeof(Program),
    new CSharpArgumentInfo[] {
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
    }));
```

and the associated set would be something like:

```
CallSiteContainer.setLengthSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
    "Length",
    typeof(Program),
    new CSharpArgumentInfo[] {
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.Constant | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null)
    }));
```